# Turning off specific hard drives due to inactivity

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Is there a built-in tool in Windows 7 (or perhaps any software out there) that can turn off *SPECIFIC* hard drives due to inactivity? I have a few backup hard drives that I don't want spinning when they are not being backed up to. I know that there's a general setting in Windows 7 that affects all hard drives, but I want to be able to apply this setting to only specific ones. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your drives use the SATA interface, try [USB Safely Remote](http://safelyremove.com/en/index.html).